# undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am following this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/17886089/692622, here is my client.rb model file and client_controller.rb file

```
# app/models/client.rb
before_create :add_unsubscribe_hash

private

def add_unsubscribe_hash
    self.unsubscribe_hash = SecureRandom.hex
end

# app/controllers/clients_controller.rb
def unsubscribe
    client = Client.find_by_unsubscribe_hash(params[:unsubscribe_hash])
    client.update_attribute(:subscription, false)
end
```

but when I am trying to add clients through /clients/new (I have all the 7 methods in controller file too), I am getting error

```
undefined local variable or method `add_unsubscribe_hash'
```

The error is coming while saving client in create method

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @client.save
```

any idea what is wrong since everything looks alright

**EDIT** - I have added the model code at pastebin http://pastebin.com/jkegLsaE

Comment: have you run the migration? `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: @creativereason - yes I have

Comment: Please post your _entire_ model code.

Comment: @zeantsoi - Hi, I have added the full model code here  http://pastebin.com/jkegLsaE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that in line 40 of [your Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/jkegLsaE), you've opened a `foreach` loop that *should* terminate on line 42, but *doesn't*. Instead, the `foreach` loop encompasses the entire `add_unsubscribe_hash` function declaration, so it's not callable by the `:before_create` callback.

Resolve this by concluding the loop within the function it should be closed in (and ensure that you remove the extraneous `end` tag at the end of the file):

```
# app/models/contact.rb
def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
        Contact.create! row.to_hash
    end
end
```